# Remove thousand separator from string

Tags: java, string

Ive been trying to remove a thousands separator from this string but with no luck.

I have tried a `trim()`, `replace("\\s")` and unicode values like `'\u00A0'`, `'\u2007'`, `'\u202F'` but with no luck. Picture below shows the string

[image]

Comment: Why is it there in the first place, can this be fixed by changing the code that formats the number?

Comment: this value is comming from an external source (api) and i cant seem to convert it into BigDecimal because of the space.

Comment: Just replace everything which is *not* a digit or `[.+-]` with an empty string

Comment: i tried replace empty string as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character you see is a non-breaking space: `\u00a0`. You can get rid of it using `String.replace`, for example.

```
value = value.replace("\u00a0", "");
```

Comment: no it doesnt as you can see in my post i tried that

Comment: or is there a difference between upper case "A" and "a" in \u00a0",

Comment: No difference. It's the same unicode character: 160 in decimal like in your screenshot, 00A0 in hexadecimal.

Comment: this worked but funny that i actually tried this before

Answer (score 0):

In general when filtering a user input it's a bad idea to try to remove all bad characters, you need to keep only good ones :) So instead of trying to make a list of bad separators just negate a list of characters allowed to be in a number.

```
value = value.replace("[^0-9.+-]", "");
```